# Project structure for extending an external third-party Django app

Tags: django

I'd like to extend django-registration with some custom forms and templates.  What's the best practice for structuring your project to include these customizations?  Would I just add my own 'registration' app and include the forms and templates there?

I know this is one of the strengths of Django, but I couldn't find any specific guidance on where to put this stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily customize the templates by creating a folder inside your templates directory named the same name as the app's template directory name you are overriding.

For example: if the app you want to override a template file in has the following structure:

```
django_registration/
    templates/
        django_registration/
            login_form.html
```

(it is standard practice to create a sub template directory named the same as the app name) Then you just have to create a file with the same name, in a sub directory of your templates directory named `django_registration`:

```
my_app/
    templates/
        django_registration/
            login_form.html
```

You can also just override any of the views and form classes that you need, and just import those classes instead of `django-registration`'s classes